# What is the context of a function in an array?

Tags: javascript

This is something that I'm sure I should know the answer to, but either I'm just being stupid or I've just somehow never come across this before...

Given the following array, declared in the global scope:

```
var arr = [function() {
    console.dir(this);
}];
```

I would have expected `this` to refer to the Window object. However, when calling the function:

```
arr[0]();​ //Logs Array
```

It appears that `this` actually refers to the array. Then, when I store a reference to the function in another variable and call that, `this` *does* refer to the Window object:

```
var func = arr[0];
func(); //Logs Window
```

So, why does the context of the function change? Here's a [fiddle demonstrating the above two cases](http://jsfiddle.net/TVtwr/).

Comment: `this` refers to the owner so I guess the owner is looked up at execute time. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call a function as property of an object, such as `obj.func()`,  `this` refers to `obj`.
This is exactly what you are doing here. `arr` is your object and `0` is the property holding a function.

**Note:** After all, arrays are just objects and their elements are the values of their properties (though properties are typically numerical strings (all properties are strings)).

See [MDN - `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for more information, in this case:

> When a function is called as a method of an object, its `this` is set to the object the method is called on.

In your second case, you call the function "standalone", hence `this` refers to `window`. If the code was run in strict mode though, `this` would be `undefined`.

Comment: More precisely `window` **is** an object and every global **is** an argument of `window`.

Comment: "After all, arrays are just objects"... that makes it make perfect sense. I was just being stupid. Thanks.

Comment: @freakish: How is this related to the question? `this` refers to `window` even if the variable is not global. In the OP's code, `func` could also be a local variable in some other function. I assume you mean global variables are *properties* of `window`.

Comment: @James: This is an interesting question though. I have to admit that  I never really thought about it.

Comment: @FelixKling - Yeah, I had never really thought about it either (hence the question). It's obvious though now I have the answer. I knew it would be something simple that I should really have been able to figure out. Thanks again :)

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, that's what I meant: property.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `this` keyword is actually an operator which returns the reference to the holder (or owner) of a function where it was called. Since in first case the holder is an array (which is an object) it returns an array. In the second case the holder is the window object.

See [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

be noted:

**in JavaScript, `this` always refers to the function owner.**

you can read more about it [at quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).

Answer (score 0):

Because the element is a member of the array, and `this` *always* points to the owner object (unless you play with `bind()`/ `call()`/ `apply()` etc). If you're not part of an object, `this` will be the global object; which is `window` in the browser environment. The exception to this is if you're in strict mode, where `this` [will be `undefined`](http://jsfiddle.net/HXcNM/).

What you're doing is effectively the same as:

```
var ar = {
    '0' : function () {
         console.dir(this);
     }
}

ar[0]();
var func = ar[0];
func();
```

... which may make more sense conceptually.

http://jsfiddle.net/TVtwr/1/

Comment: Its not quite the same. An array is a different "type" with different behavior to a plain object.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: I meant in terms of the resolution of `this`.